# What is the significance of "Wrong Number" in Hotline Miami 2?

Tags: hotline-miami-2

What does the name "Wrong Number" mean in Hotline Miami 2? What is the significance of the phrase, in terms of the plot and storyline?

I've seen a bunch of theories out there, including one saying that the ending of Hotline Miami 2 is not actually part of the real timeline (due to the split timeline in HM1).  So why use the word Wrong Number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hotline Miami 2: Wrong Number exists because Jacket got the Wrong
>   Number, thus, not ending the plans of 50 Blessings and dooming all of
>   the characters to death or nuclear holocaust (aka: death).

http://steamcommunity.com/app/274170/discussions/0/617330227194121372/#p1

this should clarify more.